# Etiquette in responding to service desk email

Tags: politeness

I just asked EA Support to send me a serial to my old game(Battlefield 2142) and they did it. Should I replay and say "thx a lot" or should I just enjoy my game and ignore them?

EA is an english company, so I'm asking how would you act in english speaking country like US or GB.

I do feel they did an amazing job and thought I would have to fight really hard and long for that serial number(and it would end up with me buying a new copy of the game).

Comment: This is also a good question, but I don't think it is really on topic.

Comment: @Cerberus I think its a useful question for people learning english culture and this is what this site is really about.

Comment: Well technically it is not much about the English culture but about how to use the English language. It could have its home in gaming maybe, although it may be necessary to check their FAQ to be sure.

Comment: Thank you for your participation but... No, this site is *not* about learning English culture. This site is for "English Language & Usage." I did not close this question solely because the accepted answer addressed the tidbit of "English language" you accidentally swerved into in the question. If you have any questions about the English language and its usage, please feel free to come by and ask again.

Comment: I would also avoid "thx a lot" as that can be taken in Britain as being sarcastic is response to a reply that did not help at all.

Comment: If anyone *is* interested in English culture, it would fit nicely into the proposed [Etiquette](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/53721/etiquette?referrer=LgE77vYHWgf6-xaTTJQACA2) site on Area51. It's currently in commitment phase but the number of interested people is slowly creeping up so hopefully it should make it to beta.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Definitely not

> thx a lot

The abbreviation is sloppy and implies you're not prepared to take the time to reply decently. As I Brit, I'd write

> Thank you for taking the time to send me the serial number, I really appreciate it

Comment: thx, I meant to write something like this, but I did not know how to put it in words :)

Comment: @010 You're welcome. Amusingly, you didn't get the message, as you continue to write 'thx' >;-)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question, I really appreciate it

Comment: @010 +1 for learning skills :D

Answer (score 5):

The kindest thing you can do for just about anybody is to make his job easier.  The CSR (customer-service representative) has you on his list of "tickets" and his whole job is to keep that list from getting too long.  An email that says "Thanks" doesn't help him at all and he has to take the time to read it.  An email that says "Thanks, *that worked*" allows him to confidently close the ticket, which, when his boss reviews his stats at the end of the month or the quarter, makes the CSR look incrementally better.

Comment: I agree.  A quick e-mail to say "that worked" allows the ticket to be closed immediately... otherwise it may hang around until the CSR concludes "if it was still a problem this guy would have got back in touch by now"...

Answer (score 2):

There would be no harm in sending a thank-you message.

You can explain your expectation and the much-better-than-expected service you received, and the technician who responded might forward that to his or her manager for inclusion in his or her employment file.

Comment: Good advice. But do keep the thank-you note short and to the point.